# How can I get reference to ModelState property in my ActionFilter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

This is my class which is basically used for UnitForWork pattern i.e save everything in a transaction:

```
public class TestFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
            if (filterContext.HttpContext == null)
                throw new NullReferenceException("null");
            else
            {
                ObjectContext objectContext = (ObjectContext)filterContext.HttpContext.Items
                                                                [ObjectContextManager.TestContext];

                if (objectContext != null)
                {
                    objectContext.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This works fine. However, I also want to make sure that it is only saved if the ModelState.IsValid property is true in my action method. How can I do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`filterContext.Controller` gives you reference of `ControllerBase` rather than `Controller`. if you cast it to `Controller` it will give you access to `ModelState` which is a public property of controller class like

```
var val = ((Controller)filterContext.Controller).ModelState.IsValid;
```

Currently, i have no idea what are the implications of this casting. Please inquire a bit about consequences before using.
**UPDATE:**
you can also access Modelstate property like

```
filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState
```

and it involves no casting